# How to post HTML message in Facebook wall using Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

How to post a message text having HTML codes in it, in FB wall using Javascript SDK?

Currently normal posting is showing HTML codes in wall.
Here is my Code -

```
$message = 'has shared this offer through <a href="http://www.google.com/">Test App</a>.<p/>-Thanks';

FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
        message : $message,
        picture : imgSrc
    }, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log('Error occured');
            alert('Error : ' + response.error);
        } else {
            alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
            console.log('Post ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I couldn't do this, i think facebook no longer allows to post a message using JavaScript SDK

Comment: nope. u can. try the FB.api . http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook doesn't allow you to post HTML.

You can do line breaks with `\n` carriage returns, and any URLs will be automatically hyperlinked:

```
$message = "has shared this offer through Test App (http://www.google.com/)\n\n-Thanks";
```